# Intercept outgoing HTTP requests

Tags: java, api, unit-testing, http, proxy

so I'm looking for a library or some way of intercepting any outgoing HTTP requests from my Java application? Why? Because I want to unit test an API integration and since I'm using a library (wrapper) for that API, I can't modify any of it's code. It's not my code that's actually making the HTTP requests.

So, I need to intercept them, view them and assert they are correct according to the API's documentation.

I've tried looking online, but I couldn't find the exact thing I'm looking for. Most libraries out there will let me do it, only if I configure the requests themselves properly, but I can't do that, since they're made by an API wrapper, not my code.

Cheers

P.S Some example code

```
String path = "/some/path";
String repoOwner = "John Doe";
String repoName = "John repo"

GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient();
client.setCredentials(this.username, this.password);

RepositoryService repositoryService = new RepositoryService(client);
CommitService commitService = new CommitService(client);

Repository repo = repositoryService.getRepository(repoOwner, repoName);

List<RepositoryCommit> commits = commitService.getCommits(repo, null, path);
```

This will use the API wrapper to get all the commits in a given repository. Suppose I wanted to see the HTTP requests this code is making and then I wanted to Unit Test them and assert they are correct. How would I do that? Is there any way to intercept them, catch them kind of like an exception, and do stuff with them, such as assertions?

Comment: Use can use either some interceptor or aspect to do so.

Comment: @Frank, could you please elaborate? I've never heard of those before.

Comment: If it isn't a off topic yet please provide some code and explain better what you're trying to do. After reading your question again I'm not sure if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @Frank, sorry, I've added some example code now and a bit more clarification. I'm using this wrapper - https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not easy and from my point of view it doesn't make much sense.

You're trying to test your application **but mostly you're trying to test the GitHubClient library**.

If I were you I would use only mocks in your tests and verify the input arguments. So the test would like like this (using [mockito](http://mockito.org/%20mockito)):

```
List<RepositoryCommit> commits = new ArrayList<>();
commits.add(new RepositoryCommit(....));
commits.add(new RepositoryCommit(....));
when(commitService.getCommits(repo, null, path)).thenReturn(commits);
```

That way you avoid of the library testing.

If you want to actually investigate what the library does - what requests it sends and what is going on - I would recommend you to **go through the library code**, find the place where the request is actually set up and just run your app in **debug mode and add a breakpoint there**.

If you really want to handle (e.g. log, replicate...) the real requests to GitHub even in production you could use AspectJ for that. That would change the byte code so that you could wrap particular method calls. Again you would have to find the place in the GitHub library where the real GitHub (I suppose HTTP) call is performed and attach aspect to that call. In aspect you basically declare which method you want to intercept and what you want to do before its call or after. I'm not really expert in this area so I can't provide you more info - there is a tutorial about Aspects - https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/starting.html

Other option is also install some network watch tool like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

EDIT

Other option how to avoid costly calls to GitHub is to create a simple wrapper like this:

```
public class GitHubServiceImpl implements GitHubService {
    private Rpository repo;

    /** other methods **/

    @Override
    public List<RepositoryCommit> getAllCommits(String path) {
        return commitService.getCommits(repo, null, path));
    }
}
```

And here is the actual service you want to test.

```
public class CommitService {

    private GitHubService gitHubService;

    private String path;

    public List<RepositoryCommit> getAll() {
        return gitHubService.getAllCommits(path);
    }

}
```

and for integration tests create special implementation of the GitHubService interface:

```
public class TestGitHubService implements GitHubService {

    private Map<String, RepositoryCommit> preArrangedCommits;
    /** other methods **/

    public void setPreArrangedCommits(Map<String, RepositoryCommit> preArrangedCommits) {
        this.preArrangedCommits = preArrangedCommits;
    }

    @Override
    public List<RepositoryCommit> getAllCommits(String path) {
        return preArrangedCommits;
    }
}
```

and in the test call:

```
public class CommitServiceIntegrationTest {
    // @Autowired, @Bean maybe?
    private CommitService commitService;

    // @Autowired, @Bean maybe?
    private GitHubService gitHubService;

    public void testGetAll() {
        Map<String, RepositoryCommit> preArrangedCommits = new HashMap<>();
        preArrangedCommits.put("path/", new RepositoryCommit(...));
        gitHubService.setPreArrangedCommits(preArrangedCommits);
        List<RepositoryCommit> commits = commitService.getAll();
        assertEquals(commits, preArrangedCommits);
    }
}
```

I would go this way.

Frank

Comment: The main reason I want to unit test this is so that if anyone changes my code, i.e. the way I've implemented the library into our product, they won't be able to break it. I also want to avoid actually running the methods I'm testing, because they take a long time to communicate with GitHub, which in a big project with hundreds of tests is not ideal. We use Jenkins and Sonar and all tests are ran automatically, when we push to the main repo. I'm basically looking for a way to reduce the time it takes for my tests to run by avoiding to wait for a response from GitHub's server.

Comment: See the answer update